# Pycharm Console Does Not Print Dots

Tags: python, pycharm

I am running PyCharm 2022.3.2.

If I `print('...')` I get blank output in both Python Console and IPython Console. This does not happen if I run Python from the terminal.

This happens with any multiples of three dots at the start of the line. Every three dots are converted to blanks. Does not happen if there is something else before the dots. e.g. `print('...-...')` gives `-...`.

Is there some setting I am missing? Is it a bug? How can I fix this?

Comment: @jasonharper Yes, it does. I tried searching for it before posting. Thanks for the link.

Comment: The reason: `...` at beginning of line is also the secondary prompt of python/iphyton. PyCharms just cannot distinguish it (if the output was done by python or by the program). Hoping that PyCharm (and Python) will finally get it (like we can do in shells, by marking the prompt)